# cannot install hibernate(5.6.0) with intellij(m1chip silicon) in java

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea, hibernate.cfg.xml

I try to run hibernate 5.6.0 in java 16 and I am programming with intellij 2021.2 for apple sillicon. When I run it I get this error:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Could not locate cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cfg.xml]
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:53)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:260)
    at mcrpg.mmorpg.Hibernate.start(Hibernate.java:11)
    at mcrpg.mmorpg.Start.main(Start.java:7)
```

My hibernate.cfg.xml is in source root:[source tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21Xvi.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Always** include the resource files in the separate **resources** directory. As by default, Maven (and so IDE as well) will not copy the resource files from the **source** directory.